# Applying if statements to for loops

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I am trying to use an if statement within a for loop to compare the values of two columns of a dataframe against each other.  A sample of three relevant vectors in my data frame is shown here.

```
HA
1.2
1.2
1.5
0.547502826
1.7
2.4
1.2846
0.5
0.466394974

HB
11.5,
10.5,
10.95,
0.547502826,
7.6,
6.7,
3.547,
3.85,
3.346972572,

HC
13.75,
11.55,
14.95,
0.547502826,
15.9,
11.05,
5.341,
3.75,
4.545342419,
```

What I want the loop to do is remove rows where HA and HB have identical numbers.  I have tried to do this using this section of code to remove these lines from the dataframe shown here as the object "data".

```
for(i in rmvalue){
if(as.numeric(rmvalue[i,"HA"])==as.numeric(rmvalue[i,"HB"])){
  data<<-rmvalue[-i,]
}
```

R however only appears to evaluate the first expression in the data frame.  Not sure how to proceed or if this process can be performed without an if statement  as a workaround.

Comment: Just try `data<-rmvalue[rmvalue[,"HA"]!=rmvalue[,"HB"],]`.

Comment: R isn't Java. It is a vectorized language. I would suggest reading some R tutorials. This will consume some time at first, but will save you lots of unnecessary headache as above in the future.

Comment: Thanks for all your feedback everyone!  I am actually new to programming in general only having just finished "Introductory R" by Robert Knell and Coursera's "Data Scientist's Toolbox" and "R-Programming."  I must admit that I have also dabbled in Java with Codecademy for fun which was likely confusing me.  Finding the work fun but also at times intensely difficult as no one else in the office uses R.  Cheers to an open source community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other commentators have noted you're speaking R with a Java accent, but that's not bad! Everyone who learns R form another language goes through something like this because you apply your old mental model to the new language. Generally R doesn't like loops and rewards vectorized solutions. In this case subseting is a quick and succinct way of doing the job:

```
D=data.frame(
      HA=c(1,1.2,1.5,0.547502826,1.7,2.4,1.2846,0.5,0.466394974),
      HB=c(1.5,10.5,10.95,0.547502826,7.6,6.7,3.547,3.85,3.346972572),     
      HC=c(13.75,11.55,14.95,0.547502826,15.9,11.05,5.341,3.75,4.545342419)
    )

D2 <- D[ D$HA != D$HB, ]
```

That said, under the hood R is running a loop, it's just that that loop is written in a more performant language. So it's actually a good aid to understanding to write loops sometimes, although you should try to not use them in real code. For your example I think I would write it as a loop like this:

```
library(dplyr) # for bind_rows    
list <- vector(mode = "list", length = length(D$HA))

for(i in seq_along(D$HA)){
  if(as.numeric(D[i,"HA"])!= as.numeric(D[i,"HB"])){
    list[[i]] <- D[i, ]
  }
}

D2 <- bind_rows(list)
```

Basically this i just a longer, slower, way of subsetting, but it's a form that underlies a lot of R code. This is basically what `lapply()` is doing.

Answer (score 3):

As David mentioned, you are not using R properly which would make more challenging problems appear impossible.

To attempt to answer your question, I would quickly write the following, assming you have your `data.frame` as specified below.

```
D=data.frame(
 HA=c(1.2,1.2,1.5,0.547502826,1.7,2.4,1.2846,0.5,0.466394974),
 HB=c(11.5,10.5,10.95,0.547502826,7.6,6.7,3.547,3.85,3.346972572),     
 HC=c(13.75,11.55,14.95,0.547502826,15.9,11.05,5.341,3.75,4.545342419)
)

result <- D[D$HA!=D$HB,]
```

Hope this points to a better direction.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Nikos 's answer is to use `dplyr`. I suggest this package because it makes the syntax easier to follow for those new to R and vectorisation (IMO)

```
install.packages("dplyr")
require("dplyr")
HA <- c(1.2, 1.2, 1.5, 0.547502826, 1.7, 2.4, 1.2846, 0.5, 0.466394974)
HB <- c(11.5, 10.5, 10.95, 0.547502826, 7.6, 6.7, 3.547, 3.85, 3.346972572)
HC <- c(13.75, 11.55, 14.95, 0.547502826, 15.9, 11.05, 5.341, 3.75, 4.545342419)
d <- data.frame(HA, HB, HC)
d1 <- filter(d, HA != HB)
```